# What is jitter variance in networking?

Tags: networking, delay, packet, variance, jitter

Let's say I have a buffer. Packets arrive at the buffer and some of them are exiting the buffer (or all of them according to the parameters I'm giving into the system). I would like to ask the following question.

When we want to calculate the jitter variance in the points:

{point before the buffer, point after the buffer},

do we calculate the time difference between these points, aka :
time in which packets exited - time in which packets entered the buffer?

or jitter variance is the time difference: 
time entering the buffer - time when first got transmitted from the source?

time exiting the buffer - time when first got transmitted from the source?

or
the difference of time between each packet of the stream (between them packet 1-packet 2, packet 2-packet 3,...and so on..)

1. entering the buffer
2. exiting the buffer

Comment: What is it you want, how to calculate network jitter or what it's network jitter? Choose one of the two questions cause I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: If I know what is network jitter I can calculate it. I need a definition.

Comment: Maybe, is jitter the time difference between subsequent packets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network jitter, is the variance in time delay between data packets over a network. For example, 
If you have “computer A” communicating with “computer B”, the two will transfer data packets. Over a healthy network, the packets travel in equal time intervals. When there is jitter, these intervals become unequal. To calculate jitter, the corrected standard deviation is used. For this, imagine you transmit 3 packets and packet 1 takes 1.2 s, packet 2 1.7 s and packet 3 1.1 s, then find the average (1.2 + 1.7 + 1.1)/3 = 1.3, then find the squared deviation like (1.2-1.3)^2 + (1.7-1.3)^2 + (1.1-1.3)^2 = 0.21, finally the jitter is SquareRoot (0.21 / (3 - 1)) = 0.34. Note the -1 in (3 - 1) is always used, this is called Bessel's correction and it unbias the calculation. For the general formulae and in depth explanation with easy to understand examples of how to calculate standard deviation, squared deviation and unbiasing them see [Standard Deviations Formulas](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation-formulas.html) and for a concrete example on jitter see [this](http://customers.watchguard.com/articles/Article/How-is-jitter-calculated).

Comment: Thank you! And as a result, if we want to compute the network jitter, we calculate these time intervals? Meaning, we calculate the time difference in which each packet is transmitted? packet 1 , t1  and packet 2 t2, and so on. jitter variance = t2-t1;

Comment: @maryyyy I edited the answer to include a very simple calculation example.

Comment: I have one extra question. If we know the time of arrival of 2 subsequent packets 1 and 2, t1, t2, where t2>t1, the difference: Δt=t2-t1, does it have a particular name? Can we call this difference again something like jitter? (I got the definition of jitter you gave above, but again these two packets and all that packets may have a time difference between them (they all got sent from the same source))

Comment: First, **all** packets will have a time difference between them **if** they come from the same source since packets are transmitted one after the other (assuming they come from the same network card). Also, jitter can only be determined and defined with **more** than 2 packets, since only one time delay could be the network path time delay, you need more time delays to establish a variance among them (jitter). **If** you only have 2 packets then only you can say is that it's the time delay between them, or the round-trip time (if packet 1 was from source to destination and packet 2 viceversa).

Comment: I got confused because of this article page 8/17, which says "Since jitter is always calculated based on two packets, ..."  https://www.xenanetworks.com/wp-content/uploads/xenadocuments/Latency-Jitter-WP.pdf

Comment: and again these 2 articles, which take the time difference between packets
https://www.pcwdld.com/network-jitter
https://www.pingman.com/kb/article/what-is-jitter-57.html

Comment: They don't use only 2 packets, they use every subsequent duple of packets. That is, given 2 packets find their delay, with the next two do the same and in real time update the jitter calculation. You have to note that they are doing the same calculations just by using simple math properties. It's the same to get the average of every n-tuple and then add it together than to add every single measure and average it. Oh, and you can also call the time delay between two packets their latency.

Comment: They do the same, its a simple algebra. They're using the summation and division properties to allow them to calc jitter in real time, instead of calculating at the end of transmission.

Comment: really thank you! and one last question. we take the average , as you stated in your answer above, so if we want the variance, we use such a calculation http://customers.watchguard.com/articles/Article/How-is-jitter-calculated

Comment: Also note that, the most accurate way is to calc it at the end of transmission. Real time calculation is an iterative procedure, the results get better as more packets arrive. That's why in the limit, the actual result is obtained, as far as the duration of transmission is concerned

Comment: Yes indeed. You can use those formulaes if you need the extra statistical properties.

Comment: really sorry for flooding you with questions, I really hope this is my last one. If I count the jitter between 2 points (before and after a buffer for example (in matlab)), and at the end of the buffer I see that some packets got lost. for example 902 packets arrive 708 packets leave.I do calculate the jitter between the packets that remain, right? Or in order to calculate the jitter, you should not have packet loss

Comment: No need to worry about flooding me with questions :-) Yoh should always ask any and every doubt. And yes, you should calculate the jitter of **all** 902 packets.

Comment: In accordance to what you told me,I concluded that taking the average as you mentioned is a good practice, so I will work as this example cites. http://customers.watchguard.com/articles/Article/How-is-jitter-calculated In the lattency calculation delay=time packet arrives before the buffer - time packet exits the source (packet generator for example) ,if my point of interest is ,lets say, jitter before a  buffer (same tactic if my point of interest was a point after the buffer, and again similar tactic if i want to find the jitter between points of interest: before and after the buffer

Comment: You should always take time measures with respect to the same reference point. That is, packets at the entrance of the buffer **or** packets after the buffer, but don't mix both reference points measures. However, you can do both but for that you must calculate everything with respect to before the buffer and repeat all calculation with respect to after the buffer, **but** do not mix these results, just present them as two jitter values, *jitter before the buffer* and *jitter after the buffer*. You can also show latency results if you want to show how much buffer processing takes on average.

Comment: So let's say I have a network topology as such: 
Packet Generator -Router 1- Router 2 - Playback buffer and I want to calculate 2 jitter values 1 before the buffer and one after the buffer. the delay=lattency for my calculations will be dt=time a packet arrives before the playback buffer-packet exits the packet generator and respectively after the playback,
dt=packet exits the playback buffer - packet exits the packet generator or dt = packet exits the playback buffer-packet arrives before the playback buffer? they all seem correct to me :p

Comment: For the jitter before the buffer dt=time a packet arrives before the buffer - time it exits the generator. For the jitter after the buffer dt=time a packet exits the buffer - time it exits the generator. Your last proposed option is valid **but** it will give you jitter and latency **of** buffer processing only, **not** the network jitter and latency.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what is it exactly that you're building/testing/designing/working on?

Comment: I have this network topology, firstly I perform some metrics on this system, like jitter, histograms, packet loss,  and then I create some policies regarding the routers about the packets (which have some priority, some of them are external traffic, policies on the queues of the buffer like fifo etc.) I got curious about jitter though, because I didn't find a clear answer on the web.

Comment: As well, if I have 3 packets lattency1=1.2 , lattency2=1.7 lattency3=0, do I act like this (1.2+1.7)/2 or (1.2+1.7+0)/3. maybe the 1st approach is correct, because the 3rd packet has no jitter so I must exclude it

Comment: Latency and jitter are **two** different things. First, **there is no such thing as 0 latency**, every event in the universe must take a finite, larger than 0 amount of time. But maybe, the latency was smaller than the machine epsilon (resolution) and hence was set as 0, in this case, you should change 0 for the machine epsilon (smallest representable value), because accepting 0 latency is a conceptual error. That is if you want to be accurate about your measures, if you don't then simply discard that packet from the calculations.